# Is there built-in support for automatically escaping invalid HTTP Header characters in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-headers, .net-core, encode

In .NET Framework, there is the method `System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.HeaderNameValueEncode()` to (as the name suggests) encodes characters (such as newlines) that would be invalid in HTTP Headers so that they are appropriately escaped.

Is there an equivalent method in .NET Core?  I'm aware of `System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode()`, but this encodes more than is needed (such as single quotes) for HTTP Headers.

EDIT:
This question is NOT a duplicate, I'm not looking for escaping characters in URLs, I'm looking for built-in functionality for escaping characters in HTTP Header values.

Comment: No. There's no official encoding for arbitrary headers in the spec. Which header are you encoding?

Comment: You can copy implementation of `HeaderNameValueEncode`, since it's pretty simple.

Comment: Here it is: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/HttpEncoder.cs,94e0a765a1cfe05e

Comment: Yes, but I said "you can copy implementation".

Comment: @Evk I misread your comment, apologies.  I have already got a new method that copied the code from there, but was hoping for a built-in solution for .NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

.Net Core doesn't implement .Net Framework's HeaderNameValueEncode(). Not even version 3.

You can find and use the Mono implementation here: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Util/HttpEncoder.cs

I like more a single-method implementation using Linq, as:

```cs
    public static void HeaderNameValueEncode(string headerName, string headerValue, out string encodedHeaderName, out string encodedHeaderValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerName))
        {
            encodedHeaderName = headerName;
        }
        else
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            headerName.All(ch => { if ((ch == 9 || ch >= 32) && ch != 127) sb.Append(ch); return true; });
            encodedHeaderName = sb.ToString();
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerValue))
        {
            encodedHeaderValue = headerValue;
        }
        else
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            headerValue.All(ch => { if ((ch == 9 || ch >= 32) && ch != 127) sb.Append(ch); return true; });
            encodedHeaderValue = sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

or, if you prefer to convert only one string:

```cs
    public static string HeaderNameOrValueEncode(string headerString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerString))
        {
            return headerString;
        }
        else
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            headerString.All(ch => { if ((ch == 9 || ch >= 32) && ch != 127) sb.Append(ch); return true; });
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```